# Working to set up Youtube API credentials - Error: deleted_client The OAuth client was deleted

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to log into my youtube account to access and build a reporting job. Trouble is I set up the Web Application, and set up the OAuth consent screen with the name of the application and am getting a 401. That’s an error.

Error: deleted_client

The OAuth client was deleted.

I've already tried renaming the product name to the application name, and have an email set up. Other than that, nothing on the web really answers the question.

[This is the image of the error that i'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLiKY.png)

Comment: Have you tried this [documentation for restoring a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects?hl=en&visit_id=636892823191172297-2596637036&rd=1#restoring_a_project)? If you have deleted your project, project owners can restore a deleted project within the 30-day recovery period that starts when the project is shut down.

Comment: I should point out that I'm running this on my local 8080 instance, so I have no google cloud access.